deleted partition has caused problems with dual boot menu
2I have a partitioned ssd, with ubuntu and win 10. The problem arose when I accidentally deleted a partition in disk management in Windows. When I rebooted my system, instead of the normal menu where I can choose what I would like to boot into I was met with a cmd line interface. Please see attached photo. I'm unable to get past this screen.
Here the list of available partitions 1
Also I'm unable to boot into windows either.

You deleted the partition where your grub configuration was stored, most likely this was you Ubuntu partition. Either restore that partition or reinstall Ubuntu. First of all you can try to type exit and hit Enter to see what happens.

@mook765 done this, it simply reboots the system back into the same cmd line interface. I tried the ls command which showed all the different partition avaliable. I've added a picture for reference

Windows has a command that will fix this, boot your windows recovery media & execute the command.  You can do this with any OS that is still installed on your system, but it appears you deleted the OS that controlled boot on your system thus the grub rescue stub (many OSes can be installed, but only one will control boot; you must give ownership to another OS before deleting the OS that controls your systems boot process)

I had a similar issue once, this is caused by a grub configuration error like @mook765 said.
The easiest solution is to reinstall Ubuntu, but if you really don't want to (if you don't have a separate home partition for example) there should be a second method.
If you boot from your live boot usb, you should be able to repair grub. Mount your boot disk in the live OS and run sudo grub-install /mnt/yourdrivehere
If this doesn't work, you could follow this guide and then come back with the results for a more detailed answer. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
